# how to load activator in intellij with sbt plugin

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm a novice on sbt.
I looked at [activator project](https://github.com/typesafehub/activator)

Now I see it uses sbt and there are sbt and scala files under the project directory.
But i was sure there would also be a main sbt (like main pom) in main directory where I can open it in intellij with sbt plugin and it would open all projects in the IDE.

Can anyone please let me know how to open this project in intellij with all its dependencies? Most probably with intellij sbt plugin because it uses sbt (i mean like in maven would bring all sub dependencies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used intellij sbt plugin.

But you could try to add the [sbt idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) plugin to the [plugins.sbt](https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/blob/master/project/plugins.sbt) file.
Then you can generate the intellij idea project files with the gen-idea task.

Comment: thanks in the linked i attached i could not find which .sbt i should load into intellij with sbt plugin, there were many .sbt files int he projects dir shouldn't there be one main .sbt in the main directory?

Comment: In that case you would not load a .sbt file, but an idea file (.iml or .ipr). They are generated with the gen-idea task.